# Solver for integer program with semidefinite constraint

Tags: optimization, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

What are the possible alternative solvers available to handle these kind of problems below?

> Gurobi does not support semidefinite cones larger than $2 \times 2$. You must use another solver for this problem.

I am using semidefinite programming with CVX Gurobi and my semidefinite constraint is as follows,

$$H'AH-Q \succeq 0$$

where $H'AH$ is a positive semidefinite matrix and $Q$ is a binary diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mosek can handle mixed-integer conic optimization problems.

https://docs.mosek.com/9.0/cmdtools/mip-optimizer.html

Another possibility is YALMIP:

https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/integerprogramming/

Comment: Not mixed-integer SDPs though.

Comment: My last comment was about MOSEK.

Comment: YALMIP with MOSEK seems to work

Comment: @user11151416 Then it is because either YALMIP reformulates the problem or it does its own branch-and-bound on top of MOSEK.  Anyway, glad that it works ;).

Comment: Yes, YALMIP has two internal solvers for mixed-integer semidefinite programming relying on external solvers (cutsdp which would call Moseks MILP solver and bnb which would call Moseks SDP solver)